# How to prove by induction that $a^{2^{k-2}} \equiv 1\pmod {2^k}$ for odd $a$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $a \in $ **Z** be odd. How to prove by induction that $a^{2^{k-2}} \equiv 1\pmod {2^k}$ for all $k \geq 3$.

> My attempt: let $k=3$
>   $$\begin{align*}
> a^{2^{k-2}}-1&= a^{2^{3-2}}-1=a^{2}-1\\
> & \stackrel{\text{a is odd}}{=} (2l+1)^2-1=4l^2+4l=4l(l+1)\\ &\stackrel{\text{choose } l=2}{=} 8 \cdot 3 = 8q
> \end{align*}$$
>   or $2^3|a^2-1 \Longleftrightarrow a^2 \equiv 1\pmod {2^3}$.
>
> Induction assumption: 
>   Let us assume that claim holds when $k=n$ or 
>   $2^n|a^{2^{n-2}}-1$ or $a^{2^{n+2}} =q'2^n+1 $. 
>   Look at the statement $a^{2^{k-2}}-1$ with the value $k=n+1$. 
>   Then 
>   $$\begin{align*}
> a^{2^{n+1-2}}-1 &= a^{2^{n-2}\cdot 2}-1=(a^{2^{n-2}})^2-1\\
> &\stackrel{\text{assumption}}{=} (q')^2(2^n)^2+2q'\cdot 2^n +1 -1\\
> &= 2^n((q')^22^n+2q')=2^nq''\\
> &\Longrightarrow 2^n|a^{2^{n+1-2}}-1.
> \end{align*}$$ 
>   Claim holds, i.e. $a^{2^{k-2}} \equiv 1\pmod {2^k}$.

Comment: +1 For showing your work. I corrected the TeX a bit to get the $2^k$ inside the parentheses.

Comment: BTW, this result can be used to prove that the unit group in $\mathbb Z/(2^k)$ is not cyclic for $k\ge3$.

Comment: See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/351175/242).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the case $k=3$, you cannot *choose* $l$. You must argue that $4l(l+1)$ is a multiple of $8$, which can be done by arguing that $l(l+1)$ must be even.

Your induction step seems ok, but it could be written more simply as
$$
a^{2^{n+1-2}}-1 = a^{2^{n-2}\cdot 2}-1=(a^{2^{n-2}}-1)(a^{2^{n-2}}+1)
$$
and use that $a^{2^{n-2}}+1$ is even.

Comment: Why not choose l? Do you mean that not choose $l=2$?

Comment: @alvoutila, isn't $a=2l+1$? If so, $l$ depends on $a$.

Comment: Yes agree with that, but what are the consequences of that l depends on a? I mean why I could not choose l as a = 2l+1, as a is odd?

Comment: @alvoutila, you're *given* $a$ and so are given $l$. What happens when $a=7$?

Comment: l gets value 3?

Comment: @alvoutila, yes and so you cannot choose $l=2$ in this case. Am I missing something here?