# Show that $\mathbb{Z}^*_{15} \cong \mathbb{Z}^*_{16}.$

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism

To show that show that $\mathbb{Z}^*_{15} \cong \mathbb{Z}^*_{16},$ that is, that $\mathbb{Z}^*_{15} $ and $ \mathbb{Z}^*_{16},$ are isomorphic, must I  look at their respective Cayley tables and discover which element corresponds to which?

Or is there a smarter way to do it?

I tried the following method:

If $\alpha$ is an isomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}^*_{15}$ to $\mathbb{Z}^*_{16},$ then

\begin{align}
\alpha(1) &= 1 \\
\alpha(4)^2 &= \alpha(4)\alpha(4) = \alpha(16) = \alpha(1) = 1 \\
\alpha(11)^2 &= 1 \\
\alpha(14)^2 &= 1 \\
\alpha(2)\alpha(8) &= 1 \\
\alpha(7)(13) &= 1
\end{align}

Then $\{\alpha(4), \alpha(11), \alpha(14)\} = \{7, 9, 15\},$ because $7^2 = 9^2 = 15^2 = 1$ in $\mathbb{Z}^*_{16}.$ Moreover, $\alpha(2) = 3, 11, 5,$ or $13.$ Since $\alpha(2)\alpha(2) = \alpha(4),$ and $3^2 = 11^2 = 5^2 = 13^2 = 9$ in $\mathbb{Z}^*_{16},$ $\alpha(4) = 9.$ However, I haven't been able to deduce any other values. I can't seem to eliminate possibilities via contradiction. Is there a smarter way to do it? Or should I continue via this method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since $\vert (\Bbb Z / n\Bbb Z)^\times\vert = \phi(n)$, we see that both groups have order $8$. They are clearly abelian, so they must be isomorphic either to $$\Bbb Z/8\Bbb Z,$$ $$\Bbb Z /4\Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z / 2 \Bbb Z$$ or $$\Bbb Z / 2 \Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z / 2 \Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z / 2 \Bbb Z.$$

Computing the orders of the elements shows that for both groups there are none of order $8$ while not all are of order $2$, so we are done.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Lukas, may you explain a bit further? For example, what does $\mathbb{Z} / n \mathbb{Z}$ mean?

Comment: @RafaelVergnaud $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$ is just another way of writing $(\Bbb Z_{n}, +)$. Some people prefer this notation since the $p$-adic numbers, which have very different properties, are also denoted $\Bbb Z_p$.

Answer (score 4):

There is a "smarter" method if you have some more results available.
The group of units $U(pq)$ for two distinct odd primes $p$ and $q$ are isomorphic to $U(p)\times U(q)$, i.e.,
$$
U(15)\cong U(3)\times U(5)\cong C_2\times C_4.
$$
And we have
$$
U(2^n)\cong C_2\times C_{2^{n-2}}
$$
in general, for all $n\ge 2$. Hence $U(16)\cong C_2\times C_4\cong U(15)$.

References:

[Is my proof that $U_{pq}$ is not cyclic if $p$ and $q$ are distinct odd primes correct?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/354559/is-my-proof-that-u-pq-is-not-cyclic-if-p-and-q-are-distinct-odd-primes-c)

[How to prove that $U_{2^n}$ is isomorphic as group to $\mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_{2^{n-2}}$ for $n \ge 3$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1307905/how-to-prove-that-u-2n-is-isomorphic-as-group-to-mathbb-z-2-times-mathb)

Comment: Thank you very much!