# Why is ord$_{2^k}(5)= \frac{\varphi(2^k)}{2}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I was doing number theory in Algebra and I came across the following example:

$$\operatorname{ord}_{2^k}(5)=  \frac{\varphi(2^k)}{2} = 2^{k-2}$$

I don't understand why that is. There are no limitations set on $k$, but I suppose it doesn't bring much to consider $k<2$.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: The group in question is $(\mathbb{Z}/2^k\mathbb{Z})^*$.

Edit: As J.W.Tanner mentioned in the comment below, this works only for $k>1$. I would still like to know why.

Comment: It's not true for $k=1$, only for $k>1$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner okay I'll edit the post adding that condition.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The structure of the group $(\mathbb{Z}/2^n\mathbb{Z})^*$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/459815/the-structure-of-the-group-mathbbz-2n-mathbbz)

Comment: @AnneBauval kinda, but what benefits does the induction in the answer have in comparison to the induction that $5^{2^{k-1}} \equiv 1$ mod $2^k$?

Comment: The more precise induction proves that the order is exactly what is wanted, and not a divisor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I claim for $k \ge 2$, $5^{2^{k-2}} \equiv  2^k + 1 \mod 2^{k+1}$.
For $k=2$ it is true: $5^{1} = 1 \cdot 2^2 + 1$.
If true for $k$, then for some $a = 0$ or $1$
$$ 5^{2^{k-1}} \equiv (a 2^{k+1} +  2^k + 1)^2 \equiv 2^{k+1} + 1 \mod 2^{k+2}$$

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to do the induction that $5^{2^{k-1}} \equiv 1$ mod $2^k$?

Comment: An extra dot appears after the first congruence symbol in this answer

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Fixed it, thanks

Comment: I found a duplicate