# Proving that every group of order $4$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_4$ or $\Bbb Z^*_8$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I want to prove at any group of order $4$ is isomorphic to either $\Bbb Z_4$ or $\Bbb Z^*_8$. I know that these two groups are not isomorphic to each other because they have different order, but I cannot go further to prove at any group of order 4 should be isomorphic to either of them. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Take a non-identity element $x$ and look at possible orders of $\langle x\rangle$.

Comment: Both groups have order $4$

Comment: Which elements satisfy $x^2=x$ in both cases ?

Comment: The group $\mathbb{Z}_8^*$ is not cyclic - see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/351175/why-multiplicative-group-mathbbz-n-is-not-cyclic-for-n-2k-and-k-ge). But of course it also has order $4$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I know, but how do I show that any group of order 4 is isomorphic to either of them?

Comment: Using Cauchy's theorem with $p=2$ we see that every group of order $4$ is isomorphic to $C_4$, or to $C_2\times C_2=C_8^*$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde can you please elaborate a little more?

Answer (score 1):

Hint :

Let $e,a,b,c$ the elements of a group of order $4$ and $e$ the neutral element.

Then, either $a^2=e$ or $a^2=b$ or $a^2=c$. $a^2=a$ can be ruled out because this implies $a=e$.

Now, you have to show two things :

- Knowing $a^2$ means knowing all products of the group.
- $a^2=b$ and $a^2=c$ lead to isomorphic groups.