# $(\mathbb{Z}/2^n \mathbb{Z})^*$ is not cyclic Group for $n\geq 3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

Question is to Prove that $(\mathbb{Z}/2^n \mathbb{Z})^*$ is not  cyclic Group for $n\geq 3$.

Hint : Find two subgroups of order $2$.

I somehow feel that a cyclic group can not have two distinct groups of same order. but, I am not sure about the proof.

I have no idea how to proceed for this.

any hint would be appreciated.

Thank You.

Comment: For a proof using a different approach, see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/66043/how-to-prove-by-induction-that-a2k-2-equiv-1-pmod-2k-for-odd-a.

Comment: @lhf: I am sorry, I did not understand the connection. It would be helpful if you can give a hint how does $(a^2)^{k−2}≡1(mod2^k) \forall k≥3$ implies $(\mathbb{Z}/2^n\mathbb{Z})^*$ is not cyclic Group for n≥3.$

Comment: The order of $(\mathbb{Z}/2^n \mathbb{Z})^*$ is $2^{n-1}$ but that result proves that no element has this order.

Comment: Ok, Ok. I got it. Thank YOu.

Comment: Hint: How many elements of order $2$ would it have if it was cyclic? Can you find more than that?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: Could someone find a non-cyclic subgroup of $U(2^n)$? Is this way useful? Thanks.

Comment: @BabakS. well, once you have enough elements of order $2$, thos will give you such a subgroup.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/66043/how-to-prove-by-induction-that-a2k-2-equiv-1-pmod-2k-for-odd-a.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Follow this outline:

- $5$ has order $m=2^{n-2}$. For a proof, see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/74086/589 .
- $5^r$ and $-5^r$ for $r=2^{n-3}$ generate different subgroups of order $2$.

If you only want to prove that $(\mathbb{Z}/2^n \mathbb{Z})^*$ is not cyclic, it is enough to prove that no element can have order $2^{n-1}$. For a proof, see [How to prove by induction that $a^{2^{k-2}} \equiv 1\pmod {2^k}$ for odd $a$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/66043/how-to-prove-by-induction-that-a2k-2-equiv-1-pmod-2k-for-odd-a).

Comment: This Hint seems much difficult. But, As you have explained, No odd Integer has order $2^{n-1}$ (For even, order is at most n). So, $(\mathbb{Z}/2^n \mathbb{Z})^*$ has no element of order $2^{n-1}$ So is not cyclic.

Comment: This edited version is more clear :). I see that $5^r, -5^r$ has order 2 for $r=2^{n-3}$. $5^r.5^r=5^{2r}=5^{2.2^{n-3}}=5^{2^{n-2}}=1$ (as any odd integer has order $2^{n-2}$ in $(\mathbb{Z}/2^n \mathbb{Z})^*$). So, we have $\big< 5^r\big>=\{1,5^r\}$ and similarly,$\big< -5^r\big>=\{1,-5^r\}$ which are two different groups of order 2. :)

Comment: Not directly related, but just a comment: In fact $o(3)=o(5)=2^{n-2}$.

Answer (score 10):

Making lhf's fine (+1) answer perhaps a bit more concrete. There are three subgroups of order two: $H_1=\{1,-1\}$, $H_2=\{1,2^{n-1}+1\}$ and $H_3=\{1,2^{n-1}-1\}$. The non-1 element in each subgroup has square $\equiv1\pmod{2^n}$ as expected.

Comment: The subgroups $H_2$ and $H_3$ are the subgroups in lhf's second bullet.

Answer (score 9):

Here is a simple way to do this :

1. $U(8) = \{[1],[3],[5],[7]\}$, and check that
   $$
   [3]^2 = [5]^2 = [7]^2 = [1]
   $$
   so $U(8)$ is not cyclic (it doesn't have an element of order $4 = |U(8)|$)
2. Since $8 \mid 2^n$ for $n > 3$, we have a natural ring homomorphism
   $$
   \mathbb{Z}/2^n\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z}, \text{ given by } [x]_{2^n} \mapsto [x]_8
   $$
   which induces a surjective group homomorphism
   $$
   U(2^n) \to U(8)
   $$
   Since the quotient of a cyclic group must be cyclic, it follows that $U(2^n)$ cannot be cyclic for $n\geq 3$

Comment: you may refer book ""AA classical introduction to modern number theory" by Kenneth Ireland, Michael Rosen

Answer (score 2):

Consider $\pm(2^{k-1}+1)$. What is the order of these two elements if $k\geqslant 3$? Note they are $\neq \pm 1$ if $k\geqslant 3$.