# Determine the number of elements of order $≤ 2$ in $(\mathbb{Z}/2^n\mathbb{Z})^×$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, number-theory

I have to determine the number of elements of order $≤ 2$ in $(\mathbb{Z}/2^n\mathbb{Z})^×$, and use this
to find the rank and the elementary divisors of $(\mathbb{Z}/2^n\mathbb{Z})^×$

I know that $(\mathbb{Z}/2^n\mathbb{Z})^× \rightarrow (\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z})^×$ is a well defined surjective homomorphism

Any help would be grateful.

Comment: Lhf's answer shows that $5$ has order $2^{n-2}$ and $5^{2^{n-3}}$ is not $-1$ thus  $5,-1$ generate the group.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/478447/589

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* Prove by induction that $5^{2^{n−2}} \equiv 1 \bmod 2^n$ and $5^{2^{n−3}} \equiv 1+2^{n-1} \bmod 2^n$ for $n\ge 3$.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/a/74086/589 and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/478082/mathbbz-2n-mathbbz-is-not-cyclic-group-for-n-geq-3

Comment: More hint might be needed for the dim-witted as I struggle to see how this would "determine the number of elements" of order $\leq2$ in $(\mathbb{Z}/2^n\mathbb{Z})^×$...

Answer (score 1):

We know that:
$$
\begin{cases}
 5^{2^{n-2}}\equiv1\pmod{2^n}\\
 \begin{aligned}
  \big|(\mathbb{Z}/2^n\mathbb{Z})^{\times}\big|&=\varphi(2^n)\\
  &=2^{n-1}(2-1)\\
  &=2^{n-1}
 \end{aligned}\\
 5^{2^{n-3}}\equiv2^{n-1}+1\pmod{2^n}\\
 \begin{aligned}
  -5^{2^{n-3}}&\equiv2^n-(2^{n-1}+1)\pmod{2^n}\\
  &=2^{n-1}-1\pmod{2^n}
 \end{aligned}\\
 2^n-1\equiv-1\pmod{2^n}\\
\end{cases}
$$
Hence:
$$
(\mathbb{Z}/2^n\mathbb{Z})^{\times}\cong\langle5\rangle\times\langle-1\rangle=\mathbb Z_{2^{n-2}}\times\mathbb Z_2.
$$
A group $G$ is cyclic if and only if it possesses a unique subgroup of each order dividing $|G|$ .

Since both $\langle5\rangle$ and $\langle-1\rangle$ are cyclic, $(2^{n-1}+1)$ and $(-1)$ is the unique element of order $2$ in $\mathbb Z_{2^{n-2}}$ and $\mathbb Z_2$, respectively.

Thus, the elements of order smaller than $2$ in $(\mathbb{Z}/2^n\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ and $\mathbb Z_{2^{n-2}}\times\mathbb Z_2$ are:
$$
\left.\begin{cases}
 \begin{gathered}
  2^{n-1}+1\ ,\\-1\ ,\\2^{n-1}-1\ ,\\1
 \end{gathered}
\end{cases}\right\}\cong
\left.\begin{cases}
 \begin{gathered}
  (2^{n-1}+1\,,1)\ ,\\(1\,,-1)\ ,\\(2^{n-1}+1\,,-1)\ ,\\(1\,,1)
 \end{gathered}
\end{cases}\right\}\ ,
$$
respectively, and they form a group which is isomorphic to $\mathbf{V}_4$ the Klein $4$-group.