# $\{m\in\mathbb Z_{2^n}:m\equiv 1 \mod 4\}$ is cyclic

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups

How can I prove that the multiplicative group $G:=\{m\in\mathbb Z_{2^n}:m\equiv 1 \mod 4\}$ is cyclic? I tried claiming that $G=\langle5\rangle$ but failed.

Comment: This amounts to proving the existence of [primitive roots](http://modular.math.washington.edu/edu/2007/spring/ent/ent-html/node29.html)

Comment: I recognized that and keep finding a primitive root, I'm stuck here.

Comment: I don't understand. What do you mean by *"I keep finding a primitive root"*?

Comment: Trying to find one...

Comment: Do you mean that you're trying to find a single integer $q$ such that we will always have $G = \langle q \rangle$, regardless of which $n$ is chosen?  If so, then don't do that.

Comment: No. Finding primitive roots depending on $n$.

Comment: Right.  So, if $q_n$ is a primitive root modulo $2^n$, then $G = \langle q_n \rangle$, by definition of a primitive root.

Comment: You actually do get $G=\langle 5\rangle$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Is the existence of primitive root $\mod 2^n$ is guaranteed?

Comment: @DaveWestwood yes.  See the link provided above.

Comment: [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/191199/11619) lhf gives a link to a book containing a proof. As well as other bits. See also [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/66044/11619). You should be able to prove that $5$ has the correct order using those ideas.